# htaccess rule to remove blog from URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, blogs

I have a site developed in php. The root folder contains all the files and a .htaccess file too for rewriting the pages on root. I have installed wordpress in the blog folder.

Suppose my site url is www.abc.com
It has pages on the root which are also rewrited eg www.abc.com/about-us/

No when i access the post in blog folder it it displays as 
http://www.abc.com/blog/las-vegas/

What i want is to remove the blog word from above url. i.e. the url should be 
http://www.abc.com/las-vegas/ and it should point to a page in blog folder.

At the same the rewrite rules for the root folder should work i.e www.abc.com/about-us/ should be accessible.

I had used below code

```
#RewriteRule ^$ blog/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1 [L]
```

but the above rule works only for blog folder and when we access www.abc.com/about-us/ (i.e. root file) even its redirected to blog folder.

There is below rule in root htaccess which redirects all request to a particular file. I need to find a way that the pages from the blog folder will bypass the below rule. But the rules need to be generic

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !blog
rewriterule ^(.*)$ /mintonapillow.php [L]